# Changing NavigationItem Title in viewDidAppear in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've set the `NavigationItem.title` in Interface builder for readability but in code i need to do

```
self.navigationItem.title = SomeThingThatComesFromDB
```

I've Tried to do this in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` but in first app launching the title is still the thing that I've set in interface builder.

How I can fix this?

This is my root view controller for application launch and here is the code that I'm using:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    for (Branch *b in [UserManager sharedInstance].branches) {
        if ([b.branchId isEqualToString: [UserManager sharedInstance].vendorId]) {
            self.title = b.branchName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try self.title = SomeThingThatComesFromDB

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I've Tried that too in viewDidAppear

Comment: show ur tried code , first your VC is embed in Navigation controller

Comment: How is your ViewController embedded ?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik This VC is my root view controller .

Comment: its ok your RootVC  is embed in Navigation controller

Comment: try with `self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = b.branchName;break;`

Comment: i'm using the tab bar and inside that tab bar in first tab i've added a navigation controller that point to my VC. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Lepidopteron i'm using the tab bar and inside that tab bar in first tab i've added a navigation controller that point to my VC.

Comment: can you show ur storyboard scene

Comment: use setTitle method too setting the navigation title

Comment: @vivek all of the the methods here works ! but after going to another tab and come back ! but in first lunch nothing happens

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  all of the the methods here works ! but after going to another tab and come back ! but in first lunch nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the following comparison in place to set/update the navigation item's title.

```
if ([b.branchId isEqualToString: [UserManager sharedInstance].vendorId]) {
    self.title = b.branchName;
}
```

Problem seems to be that the *[UserManager sharedInstance].vendorId]* variable is not set (yet), when you call the function to update a navigation item's title. As you are able to set it correctly, after the view had disappeared and appeared back again.

---

The below code illustrates once again how one can set a navigation item's title, as you also did:

If you want to update the title in general for all related navigation elements (UITabbarController tabs, UINavigationController back button etc.) simply use:

```
self.navigationItem.title = SomeThingThatComesFromDB
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621364-title

If you got a dedicated navigation item in your UINavigationController's bar, you could access it the following way (make sure, there is only one to access)

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = SomeThingThatComesFromDB
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = SomeThingThatComesFromDB
```

Comment: the problem here is that all of methods that anyone on this question works ! but not in first lunch ! I must go to another page and come back to make it work ...

Comment: When do you setup "[UserManager sharedInstance].vendorId"? I think this value might be null until the data was loaded from somehwere, then also the comparison could not match

Comment: Great :-) Good luck in hunting down the issue with the vendorId ;-)

Comment: that you too :D I'm new here and no reputation to give :D

Comment: Cool to have you here :-) Wish you a good time on your journey on stackoverflow and welcome you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code:

```
CGRect rect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]];
title.text = *SomeThingThatComesFromDB*;
title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

CGSize size = [title.text sizeWithAttributes:
               @{NSFontAttributeName:
                     title.font}];

title.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, size.width, rect.size.height);//40
myView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, 40+size.width, rect.size.height);

[myView addSubview:title];
self.navigationItem.titleView = myView;
```